# Why is the loop in my Java program not working?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I want to create a constructor, where I will ask the user to enter a person's name which will be stored in an ArrayList, and then ask the user to enter the phone number of that same person which will also be stored in another ArrayList. This should keep looping unless the user types in "no" which would then end the loop.

However, when I run the method in a demo class, the first iteration works fine but then the second time out, it does not work as it skips the user input of the person's name and jumps directly to the input of the phone number.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

```
public PhoneBookEntry()
{
    System.out.println("Enter the following requested data.");
    System.out.println("");
    int i=0;
    while(i==0)
    {       
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the person (enter 'no' to end): ");
        input_name = kb.nextLine();
        if(!input_name.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
        {
            name.add(input_name);
            System.out.println("Enter the phone number of that person (enter '-1' to end): ");
            input_number = kb.nextLong();
            phone_number.add(input_number);
        }
        else
        {
            name.trimToSize();
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ever write a constructor like that.

Comment: I'd advise not doing any complex work in a constructor. How are you ever going to effectively test a class that does complex IO in it's own constructor?

Comment: `kb` is not defined nor passed anywhere in the code...

Comment: Why are people down-voting this question? Because he doesn't know not to put this in a constructor? At least he tried and wrote code and seems to have researched some on his own.

Comment: @alfasin Oops sorry. I defined it outside of the constructor.

Comment: @BrianRoach So how where I do put all of stuff in, if not for a constructor? Sorry, I'm obviously pretty new tot Java.

Comment: The I/O should be done something like the one shown here: http://pastebin.com/mEvMD4QD  in  the main class where you are creating the object.

Comment: @Ranjith-SR2GF Thanks, I understand what to do from now. Your example made it very clear and simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with your Scanner object. Understand that Scanner's `nextLong()` and similar methods such as `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `next()`, do not handle the End Of Line (EOL) token. You must take pains to handle it yourself.

One way is to add a call to `nextLine()` like so:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the person (enter 'no' to end): ");
    input_name = kb.nextLine();
    if(!input_name.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
    {
        name.add(input_name);
        System.out.println("Enter the phone number of that person (enter '-1' to end): ");
        input_number = kb.nextLong();
        phone_number.add(input_number);
```

to this:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the person (enter 'no' to end): ");
    input_name = kb.nextLine();
    if(!input_name.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
    {
        name.add(input_name);
        System.out.println("Enter the phone number of that person (enter '-1' to end): ");
        input_number = kb.nextLong();
        kb.nextLine();  // **** added to handle the EOL ****
        phone_number.add(input_number);
```

End yes, the comments are right -- this is a *terrible* constructor. Constructors are not for interacting directly with the user but for creating objects only.

Comment: Since the value entered should only ever be -1, why not just read an int instead?

Comment: @Makoto: yes, `nextInt()` could be called, but the problem would still remain since this method also does not handle the EOL token.

Comment: @Makoto the value will not be -1 if the user enters a phone number. He could still use an int but it could be a different value

Comment: @jrubins:  If a phone number is entered and interpreted as an octal number (something starting with 0), it will either enter a lower value than expected or blow up on 8 or 9.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  True, but after re-reading the case, it'd be better to use nextLine() to get the line/EOL as a string, in case a number comes in with a leading 0.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, but I don't understand what that does exactly. What role does it play?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So a constructor should only be used initialization? I guess I'll shift all of this work into another method then.

Comment: @gjvatsalya: 1) a constructor sets the initial state of its object. 2) what this does is read the End of Line (EOL) token that wasn't read by the `nextLong()` Scanner call.